# How do I find a specific tag's value (which could be anything) with beautifulsoup?

Tags: beautifulsoup

I am trying to get the job IDs from the  tags of Indeed listings. So far, I have taken Indeed search results and put each job into its own "bs4.element.Tag" object, but I don't know how to extract the value of the tag (or is it a class?) "data-jk". Here is what I have so far:

```
import requests
import bs4
import re

# 1: scrape (5?) pages of search results for listing ID's
results = []
results.append(requests.get("https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=data+analyst&l=United+States&start=0"))
results.append(requests.get("https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=data+analyst&l=United+States&start=10"))
results.append(requests.get("https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=data+analyst&l=United+States&start=20"))
results.append(requests.get("https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=data+analyst&l=United+States&start=30"))
results.append(requests.get("https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=data+analyst&l=United+States&start=40"))  
# each search page has a query "q", location "l", and a "start" = 10*int
# the search results are contained in a "td" with ID = "resultsCol"

justjobs = []
for eachResult in results:
    soup_jobs = bs4.BeautifulSoup(eachResult.text, "lxml")  # this is for IDs
    justjobs.extend(soup_jobs.find_all(attrs={"data-jk":True}))  # re.compile("data-jk")
# each "card" is a div object
    # each has the class "jobsearch-SerpJobCard unifiedRow row result clickcard"
    # as well as a specific tag "data-jk"
    # "data-jk" seems to be the actual IDs used in each listing's URL

# Now, each div element has a data-jk. I will try to get data-jk from each one:
jobIDs = []
print(type(justjobs[0]))  # DEBUG
for eachJob in justjobs:
    jobIDs.append(eachJob.find("data-jk")) 
print("Length: " + str(len(jobIDs)))  # DEBUG
print("Example JobID: " + str(jobIDs[1]))  # DEBUG
```

The examples I've seen online generally try to get the information contained between  and , but I am not sure how to get the info from inside of the (first) tag itself. I've tried doing it by parsing it as a string instead:

```
print(justjobs[0])
for eachJob in justjobs: 
    jobIDs.append(str(eachJob)[115:131])
print(jobIDs)
```

but the website is also inconsistent with how the tags operate, and I think that using beautifulsoup would be more flexible than multiple cases and substrings.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The question still stands, but I fixed this specific problem by casting the Tag object as a string, then using Python's built-in find() function to look for the index of "data-jk=", and finally adding the 16 characters after that to an array.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can regex them out from a script tag

```
import requests,re 

html = requests.get('https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=data+analyst&l=United+States&start=0').text
p = re.compile(r"jk:'(.*?)'")
ids = p.findall(html)
```

---

[image]